# How detect when a Word shape is deleted or dragged in a VSTO C# project

Tags: ms-word, vsto

I'm using the command bars OnUpdate event handler to detect when a shape is selected. If a shape is selected I open an action pane to display some custom properties, which I close again when the shape is deselected.  But this event does not fire for dragging or deleting and I'm not sure it's even the correct event to use.

When I select a shape and drag it around the OnUpdate does not pick-up that it is selected and cannot not open my pane. When I select a shape and delete it the OnUpdate does not pick-up that the shape is gone and cannot not close my pane.

I've managed to detect when a shape is being dragged using the event handler:

```
WordDocument.Application.WindowSelectionChange += 
  new ApplicationEvents4_WindowSelectionChangeEventHandler(Application_WindowSelectionChange);
```

But can't determine delete. Any advice on how I can detect when a shape is deleted in a VSTO Addin?

Comment: I've edited the new information you provided into your Question. Doesn't WindowSelectionChange also fire when a graphic is selected? I don't know of any way to detect when a graphic is deleted using Word's events. The only thing I can think of would be to use the Windows API to try to track the use of the DELETE and BACKSPACE keys, but that's not always straight-forward with Office applications. Beyond that, users often do things that trigger WindowSelectionChange, so hiding the task pane would simply be somewhat delayed...

Comment: There is also a regular `Document.SelectionChange` event but I don't really recommend it for a typical use case. I've tried using it to detect whether an image is selected and it makes document navigation noticeably slower. It also has its limits, e.g. I think it doesn't fire when you use arrow keys? Word isn't really designed for this kind of thing.